# worry and worry about

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, intransitive-preposition

I learned the word **worry** contains two functions: one is as a transitive verb and the other is an intransitive verb.

However, in this two sentences, (from TOEFL)

> 1. People have a variety of factors in their lives that cause them to **worry**, such as school, jobs, and personal relationships.
> 2. Even during times when I was not actually studying, I found myself **worrying** **about** the tests and I was unable to completely relax.

I thought *worry* is a transitive verb, it must not go with preposition, such as *about*, whereas as an intransitive verb, it should involve preposition.

And I thought the **worry** in the first sentence is a transitive verb because it has object; *a variety of factors in their lives*. 
Thus, I agree with this sentence has no preposition.

However, in second sentence, I thought **worry** is a transitive verb since it has object: *the test*. Then why preposition *about* is there if **worry** in that sentence is a transitive?

Or does this word function as an intransitive verb? if so, why an object *the test* is there?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that nobody is going to answer, so let me try.
It's a bit difficult too for me to understand the difference but let me simplify your example.

I think that we can represent the **same meaning** with two different structures.

(1) The future worries me

(2) I worry about the future

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worry)

In the first case, we got

**worry** [TRANSITIVE]

> to make someone feel unhappy and frightened because of problems or
>   unpleasant things that might happen

In the second case, we got

**worry** [INTRANSITIVE]

> to think **about** problems or unpleasant things that might happen in a
>   way that makes you feel unhappy and frightened

Let's take a look at [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worry)

> **Feel** or **cause to feel** anxious or troubled **about** actual or potential
>   problems.
>
> [no object] *he worried **about** his soldier sons in the war*
>
> [with object] *there was no need to worry her*

**Feel** [INTRANSITIVE]

**Cause to feel** [TRANSITIVE]

---

Knowing all this, let's return to your example

> People have a variety of factors in their lives that **cause** them to
>   **worry**

[Simplifying] A variety of factors **worry** them. [TRANSITIVE]

> I found myself **worrying about** the tests

[Simplifiying] I **worry about** the test [INTRANSITIVE]

**about the test** is NOT the object, it is a [prepositional-clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/prepositional-phrases).